# Find the period of deferral if a monthly payment is $9000$ for $9$ years and it will start $9$ months from now on.

Tags: economics

I have some questions on how to answer these problems. These questions were asking me to find the period of deferral in each of these deferred annuity 
problems. The questions are:

> 1. Find the period of deferral if a monthly payment is $9000$ for $9$ years and it will start $9$ months from now on.
> 2. Find the period of deferral if a monthly payment is $6000$ for $6$ years and it will start at the end of $10$ years.
> 3. Find the period of deferral if there is a semi-annual payments of $12700$ for $5$ years that will start $2$ years from now.

**My work**

1. I believe that the period of deferral would be $9$ months because the payment would be delayed for $9$ months.
2. I believe that the period of deferral would be $10$ years because I gotta wait for $10$ years before I can finally pay my dues.
3. I believe that the period of deferral would be $2$ years because I can finally pay my dues after waiting $2$ years.

Are my answers correct, ladies and gentlemen?